# Decltype Bug Gcc wont compile

Tags: c++11, gcc, c++14

source code 
https://github.com/kennywakeland/Decltype-Bug/blob/master/main.cpp

Test compile 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443f03625728f00e

This code is to test the setters and getters, using macros. I want to pass in the variable name. decltype is not returning the right type to the HTestSet. Any idea why it is not returning the correct value type ?

Compiler error
    g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:26:72: error: no matching function for call to 'HTestSet(TestClass&, void (BaseClass::*)(int), int&)'
     if(HTestSet(OBGEC_ON, &decltype(OBGEC_ON)::SET_CALL, test_vall_stor)){
                                                                        ^

main.cpp:18:1: note: in expansion of macro 'H_TEST_VALUE_GET_SET'
 H_TEST_VALUE_GET_SET(H_GET_VALUE(OBGEC_ON, VAL_NAME), \
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:92:5: note: in expansion of macro 'H_TEST_VALUE'
     H_TEST_VALUE(woo, Green, 3);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What version of `g++` (find it out with `g++ -v`). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52108544/edit)  your question to provide (inside the question itself) some [MCVE]. Your `github` link don't work for me

Comment: I see what you are saying.  It works for red and blue but fails for green because decltype decides that setGreen is in BaseClass instead of TestClass (which is true) but you expected it to return TestClass for all three.  Here is a link for a simpler MCVE without all the macros: 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cac0de91cca6dda

Comment: This has nothing to with `decltype`. The issue is with `&TestClass::setGreen` being of type `void (BaseClass::*)(int)` instead of `void (TestClass::*)(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug (as far I can tell) and has nothing to do with `decltype`. The problem is that `setGreen` is a non-virtual member function of `BaseClass`, and since you did not re-declare such function in `TestClass`, the type of:

```
&TestClass::setGreen
```

is:

```
void (BaseClass::*)(int)
```

...and thus you have a template parameter conflict in your template instantiation of `HTestSet`.

---

I did not find a better standard quote for this than the example in [[expr.unary.op#3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3):

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static or variant member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C​::​m`. [...]
>
> ```
> struct A { int i; };
> struct B : A { };
> ... &B::i ...       // has type int A​::​*
> ```

---

The use of `f` at the beginning of your `main` only works because a `void (BaseClass::*)(int)` can be implicitly converted to a `void (TestClass::*)(int)` in this case, [[conv.mem#2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem#2):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class ([class.derived]) of B. [...] Since the result has type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, indirection through it with a D object is valid. The result is the same as if indirecting through the pointer to member of B with the B subobject of D.